# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "..." does not exist - through makemigrations error?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I pushed a project onto heroku and can't seem to win with the makemigrations on it.

So first I thought everything went fine. After pushing it, I did the migrations and createsuperuser. All looked good and admin worked except for one section: accounts_userprofileinfo . Once I try to click on that table in admin this error shows up:

> Internal Server Error: /admin/accounts/userprofileinfo/
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 65, in execute
>   return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column accounts_userprofileinfo.daca does
>   not exist
>
> LINE 1: SELECT "accounts_userprofileinfo"."id",
>   "accounts_userprofil...

Usually you wouldn't do makemigrations on a live-server but I thought it might fix it so I did. Surprisingly it had an outcome:

```
Migrations for 'auth':
  .heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0009_auto_20180709_2242.py
    - Alter field email on user
```

Locally my makemigrations are with outcome: no changes, but there everythings works anyway. Funny thing is with the heroku postgres that no matter how often I do the makemigrations, the same thing keeps popping up with migrations for auth, like it doesn't save it. Not sure if thats causing the server error with my account_userprofileinfo but it might.

Account Model:

```
User._meta.get_field('email').__dict__['_unique'] = True

class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
       ('yes', 'yes'),
       ('no', 'no'),
       )
    POSITION_CHOICES = (
        ('President', 'President'),
        ('Vize-President', 'Vize-President'),
        ('Secretary', 'Secretary'),
        ('Member', 'Member'),
    )
    daca = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default="no")
    committee  = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=POSITION_CHOICES, default="Member")

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=False, default='')
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=16,blank=False, default='')
    experience = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default='0')
    profile_picture = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True, default='/placeholder/neutral3.png',
                                            resize_source=dict(size=(550, 700)))
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True,editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        # Built-in attribute of django.contrib.auth.models.User !
         return self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name

    def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs["instance"]
        if kwargs["created"]:
            user_profile = UserProfileInfo(user=user)
            user_profile.save()
            post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run also manage.py migrate.  Also I am not sure you really need that `User._meta.get_field('email').__dict__['_unique'] = True`.  Monkey-patching default models causing to create new migration inside Django itself that I will say is bad. To change default fields you'd better create custom user model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model. But it's hard to make in the already created project.  So maybe handle unique check in Form.

Comment: Using the manage.py migrate didn't work, since it only kept telling me that there outstanding migrations to do from manage.py makemigrations on the online server(only). But your second tipp with removing the line "User._meta.get_field('email').__dict__['_unique'] = True" seemed to have an impact. After I updated the files, wiped the online database clean and started new makemigrations(no result, yippi) and migrations it all worked fine. Thanks!